# Find a YTD Employee Average

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm looking to find the average number of employees for the first half of 2015. Thats the head count of each month, Jan-Jun / 6 (months).  This number is the desired result.

For example, lets just do 3 months for simplicity's sake.  Jan had 100, Feb had 105, and Mar had 103.  308/3 = 102.7 average employees.

Unfortunately I've been left with only a few columns and I'd like to generate some clean code to make it simple to complete my task.  Not sure how to complete this task though with the information I have.

Code:

```
 SELECT   distinct a.personidno as 'PersonId', a.[LastHireDate], a.[TerminationDate],  --COUNT(distinct a.PersonIdNo) 
    CASE    WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Full Time' THEN 'RFT'
            WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'PRN' THEN 'PRN'
            WHEN a.EmploymentStatus = 'Regular Part Time' THEN 'RPT'
            ELSE a.EmploymentStatus
    END as 'EmpStatus'
  --into #tmp_ytd_hc_avg
  FROM [EmployeeTable] a
  where 
  a.OrgCodeIdNo = '69' and
  (a.[TerminationDate] >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and a.[TerminationDate] <= '2015-06-30 23:59:59')
  OR (a.[TerminationDate] is null and a.employeestatus = 'Active')
```

Sample Data:

```
PersonId    LastHireDate            TerminationDate         EmpStatus
19          2012-07-30 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
20          2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
21          2010-10-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
24          1994-06-28 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
25          2002-12-11 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
26          2011-03-21 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
27          2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
30          2010-06-29 00:00:00.000 NULL                    PRN
34          2008-12-16 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
35          2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
36          2014-02-27 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
37          2009-03-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    PRN
39          2012-06-25 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
40          2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
42          2011-08-01 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
44          2014-02-27 00:00:00.000 2014-09-27 00:00:00.000 RFT --hired before 2015-01-01 and leaves before 2015-01-01
54          2014-02-27 00:00:00.000 2015-05-15 00:00:00.000 RFT --hired before 2015-01-01 and leaves before 2015-06-30
676         2015-02-27 00:00:00.000 2015-06-15 00:00:00.000 RFT --hired after 2015-01-01 and leaves before 2015-06-30
3012        2015-03-20 00:00:00.000 2015-07-03 00:00:00.000 RFT --hired after 2015-01-01 and leaves after 2015-06-30
5125        2015-07-11 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RPT
5127        2015-07-07 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
5129        2015-07-09 00:00:00.000 NULL                    PRN
5131        2015-07-07 00:00:00.000 NULL                    PRN
5133        2015-07-09 00:00:00.000 NULL                    PRN
5136        2015-07-13 00:00:00.000 NULL                    RFT
```

Comment: This part `OR (a.[TerminationDate] is null and a.employeestatus = 'Active')` doesn't look right - what if they were terminated in May? They won't be counted at all. Furthermore, you seem to be checking LastHireDate to detect if they were employed, but that would give the number of _new_ employees, not the number of _current_ employees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0796f/3/0) with your updated sample data. There are two queries there: first returns just one average number, second returns daily numbers to help understand how it works. Follow the dates and you can see how the number changes as people come and go.

---

For each person you need to know two dates: when he was hired and when he left. I hope this is what `LastHireDate` and `TerminationDate` mean. I assume that `NULL` `TerminationDate` means that the person has not left yet, is still employed.

When I calculate similar reports I calculate the number of people employed for each day in the given range (rather than month). Then you can average daily numbers further as needed.

I use a `Calendar` table. This table simply has a list of dates for several decades.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendar](
    [dt] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendar] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [dt] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In my system it has few extra columns, such as `[IsLastDayOfMonth]`, `[IsLastDayOfQuarter]`, which are useful in some reports, but in your case you need just the date column. There are many ways to [populate such table](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1).

For example, 100K rows (~270 years) from 1900-01-01:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar (dt)
SELECT TOP (100000) 
    DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])-1, '19000101') AS dt
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Once you have `Calendar` table, here is how to use it:

```
WITH
CTE_EmployedPeople
-- this is how many people were employed on each day in the given period
AS
(
    SELECT
        dbo.Calendar.dt
        ,CAST(COUNT(*) as float) AS People -- without this cast the final average is int
    FROM
        dbo.Calendar
        CROSS JOIN EmployeeTable
    WHERE
        (dbo.Calendar.dt >= '2015-01-01')
        AND (dbo.Calendar.dt <= '2015-06-30')
        AND (dbo.Calendar.dt >= EmployeeTable.LastHireDate)
        AND (dbo.Calendar.dt <= EmployeeTable.TerminationDate 
             OR EmployeeTable.TerminationDate IS NULL)
    GROUP BY dbo.Calendar.dt
)
,CTE_Daily
-- if it is possible that nobody was employed on a certain day
-- left join previous results to the Calendar table again to get 0 for such days
AS
(
    SELECT
        dbo.Calendar.dt
        ,ISNULL(CTE_EmployedPeople.People, 0) AS People
    FROM
        dbo.Calendar
        LEFT JOIN CTE_EmployedPeople ON dbo.Calendar.dt = CTE_EmployedPeople.dt
    WHERE
        (dbo.Calendar.dt >= '2015-01-01')
        AND (dbo.Calendar.dt <= '2015-06-30')
)
-- simple average of daily numbers
SELECT AVG(People) AS AvgPeople
FROM CTE_Daily;
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. Could you possibly send the schema and data within your Calendar table

Comment: @tshoemake, I added details about Calendar table to the answer.

Comment: That's great thank you.  I've also added more sample data which had your suggested missing variants.

Comment: @tshoemake, I added SQL Fiddle to the answer that uses your updated sample data.

Comment: This would have taken me weeks to write.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @tshoemake, you are welcome. I've taken this query from one of my reports, I didn't write it from scratch. Which means that this kind of report is pretty common. I prefer to have daily numbers, because once you have this basis you can process/analyze it further and all derived reports would be consistent between each other. For example, you can draw a neat chart showing the history how company grew over years.

Comment: That's truly amazing.  Thank you for sharing, it just saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 2):

Go with @VladimirBaranov's answer for a generic solution.

But in your special case you might not need to calculate the employees per month and then average it. Simply summing the number of months employed within the requested range and then dividing it by 6 returns the same result.

```
 SELECT
   -- approximate monthly average 
   SUM(datediff(month, start_dt, end_dt)+1) / 6.00,
   -- exact daily average
   SUM(datediff(day, start_dt, end_dt)+1)
   / cast(datediff(day, '2015-01-01', '2015-07-01') as float)
FROM
 (

   SELECT
   LastHireDate
   ,TerminationDate
      -- fixing start date to match the requested range
   ,CASE WHEN LastHireDate < '2015-01-01 00:00:00' THEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' ELSE LastHireDate END AS start_dt
      -- fixing end date to match the requested range
   ,CASE WHEN TerminationDate <= '2015-06-30 23:59:59' THEN TerminationDate ELSE '2015-06-30 23:59:59' END AS end_dt
   FROM EmployeeTable AS a
   WHERE a.OrgCodeIdNo = '69'
      -- As @Turophile mentioned, your logic seems to be wrong, 
      -- your sample result shows employees hired after june 2015
   AND (TerminationDate >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' 
        OR (TerminationDate IS NULL AND a.employeestatus = 'Active')))
   AND LastHireDate <= '2015-06-30 23:59:59'
 ) AS dt
```

This solution will count an employee if it was hired only a single day within a month, of course this might not be a correct average based on how you define "number of employees per month".

Edit:

Added a calculation like VladimirBaranov's to get a daily average:

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0796f/11)

Comment: The report requirements are pretty much left up to me.  They just "need the report" :].  In your opinion, would @VladimirBaranov's be the best way to average it? I'm no mathematician.

Comment: @tshoemake: I'm no math guy, too :-) My query returns 17.33 and VladimirBaranov's 16.92, my query is an approximate monthly and his an exact daily average. But I just noticed that you can modify my query to get exactly the same result, I'll edit my answer...

Answer (score 1):

Could you use DATEPART?

```
SELECT
  COUNT( 1 ) / 6.0
FROM
  EmployeeTable AS a
WHERE
  OrgCodeIdNo = '69' AND
  DATEPART( YEAR, TerminationDate ) = 2015 AND
  DATEPART( MONTH, TerminationDate ) <= 6
```

Comment: I need to limit it to Jan 2015. This may work though as a start, I'll look into it tomorrow

Comment: Limiting by month is as easy as setting the last condition to the number of months in a year you wish to limit the query to and modifying the average you're dividing by. "COUNT( 1 ) / 1.0" would simply reduce to "COUNT( 1 )". Use "... TerminationDate ) <= 1" at the end to only include January.